# How to display UITableView Cells category wise?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want a UITableView to display the following data:

[image: required output]

Instead of:

[image: my current output]

The code I've used is as follows:

```
// Data model class defining an Animal
class Animal {

    // data members
    var name: String
    var type: String

    // initializer
    init(name: String, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }

}
```

and

```
// View Controller
import UIKit

class AnimalsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // an array of Animal(s)
    var animals: [Animal] = [Animal("Cat", "Domestic"), Animal("Dog", "Domestic"), Animal("Lion", "Wild"), Animal("Deer", "Wild"), Animal("Tiger", "Wild")];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

    }

    // returns the number of rows to be present in table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animals.count
    }

    // returns each cell to be present in the table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentfier = "animalbasic"
        // uses a protype cell from storyboard
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentfier)
        cell.textLabel.text = animals[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

What do I need to change, in my code, in order to get the required output?(Assume an array is always sorted Animal.type wise)

Comment: what issue faced ?

Comment: You want to treat a section as a normal cell? You need to parse `var animals` correctly, and regroup them by category (Wild, Domestic, etc.) first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to break your data into sections by type.

```
class AnimalsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var animals: [Animal] = [Animal("Cat", "Domestic"), Animal("Dog", "Domestic"), Animal("Lion", "Wild"), Animal("Deer", "Wild"), Animal("Tiger", "Wild")]

    var sections: [[Animal]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        var sectionForType = [String: [Animal]]()
        for animal in animals {
            if sectionForType[animal.type] == nil { sectionForType[animal.type] = [] }
            sectionForType[animal.type]!.append(animal)
        }
        sections = sectionForType.keys.sorted().map({ sectionForType[$0]! })
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section][0].type
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "animalbasic")!
        cell.textLabel!.text = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, even if, maybe it is working, as an experienced dev, i found it hard to read, not even talking about code style and best practices, and testability

Comment: A toy problem warrants a toy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:
use a struct for this type of things, rather than a class
for expendability I would use an `enum` for the animal type, something like:

```
enum AnimalType: String {
 case domestic = "Domestic"
 case wild = "Wild"
}
```

Note: not actually needed to make it string, you can also have a function that based on the type would return a localised string, you can write something like

```
enum AnimalType: String {
 case domestic, wild
 var localizedString: String {
    switch self {
    case .domestic: return "Domestic"
    case .wild: return "Wild"
    }
}
```

Now your struct will look like this

```
struct Animal {
    let name: String
    let type: AnimalType
}
```

and now you are able to init it like this

`let animal = Animal(name: "Cat", type: .domestic)`

Now back your problem,
I would suggest to keep the type in a section header rather than a cell, it would make more sense don't you think?

Create a variable 
`let sections = [.domestic, .wild]` now you have the count and it will also be easily extended

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionType = sections[section]

    switch sectionType {
    case .domestic:
        return animals.filter{ $0.type == .domestic }.count
    case .wild:
        return animals.filter{ $0.type == .wild }.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let sectionType = sections[section]

    switch sectionType {
    case .domestic:
        /// Configure your cell
    case .wild:
        /// Configure your cell
    default:
        assertionFailure("Should not reach in this situation")
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

ofcourse you will have to also configure the header for your sections:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let sectionType = sections[section]

    switch sectionType {
    default: sectionType.localizedString
}
```

Your approach is also doable, but this would mean that at numberOfRowsInSection you will have to add the number of sections:

```
// returns the number of rows to be present in table
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return animals.count + sections.count
}
```

and then `cellForRowAt` would be a pain to mentain, you would need to do some calculations to see what row is it, is it still wild domestic, is it wild yet

TLTR you would have a bunch of `if, if else, if else, else`, and by only 
adding one more type (dinosaur maybe) this pain will hit you back

Note: this code can be improved using a viewModel, but for the sake of being fast i skipped that part